# An O(n) sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is a homework question, so I would like to avoid complete answers and much prefer hints if possible.

Given an array of random integers A[1...x], the program should return the first y array elements in incrementing order where 1<=y<=sqrt(x). So, basically, given an array [5,9,2,8] and y=2, the program should return [2,5].

The "sort first, return first y items" answer is out the window since the best we can do is n*logn time with merge or quicksort. The answer thus has to make use of the fact that we only return at most sqrt(x) items, and the only other answer I have so far is doing a for-loop search for the minimum element in the array, removing the minimum from the array, stashing it in a new array, say B, and repeating the process on the now smaller modified version of A of length x-1, which gives us running time like so:

```
x + (x-1) + (x-2) + ... + (x-y)
```

That counts the number of for-loop iteration of the min-search, and gives us at most y or sqrt(x) iterations in the worst case scenario, and there are at most x items in the array. So we have sqrt(x)*x, which is better than O(n*logn) but still not quite O(n) :/.

Comment: Have you looked at [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)? When I see O(n) requirements it's the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: "program should return the first y *digits* ". Maybe *numbers*?

Comment: @ruslki -- yes, i meant the first y array items. Fixing that now.

Comment: O(sqrt(x)*x) = O(x^(3/2)). Any polynomial time algorithm with exponent greater than 1 is asymptotically greater than an n log n algorithm.

Comment: Hence n log n is better than sqrt(n)*n.

Comment: Practical algorithm is `quickselect` average O(n), worst case O(n^2). For hard O(N) you need median-of-medians adjusted to your conditions (for example, to select 50% of items, find median, then partition the list).

Comment: Also, if `y << x` (typical for asymptotic x), funnel the list through a min-heap, the result will be O(x * log y), which is still, technically O(n log n). But it's very practical, e.g. memory requirement is smaller than other approaches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: Suppose you had an O(n) time algorithm to pick the y<sup>th</sup> element...

Comment: Then wouldn't I have to call it sqrt(x) times? That's still sqrt(x)*y.

Comment: @thezhaba: You are going in the wrong direction. For a further hint: think about the first step in quicksort.

Comment: Seems like people downvote without even _knowing_ if what is written is right or wrong. Especially with incomplete answers with just hints, it is even more difficult to be sure if something is wrong. Ridiculous! :-)

Comment: Such algorithm would help. Another hint: prefiltering.

Comment: I don't see how this get how this can be better than O(n^(3/2))

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: `sqr(sqrt(n)) == n`

Comment: @Thomas: Another hint. You would use the O(n) algorithm above just _one_ time.

Comment: @Moron: maybe the problem that someone saw with your answer is that you need a bit better than just an O(n) selection algorithm here. IMO your comment fixes that. @ThomasMcLeod, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm (thezhaba - warning, contains spoilers).

Comment: @Steve: I guess so. I guess they also chose to ignore the first sentence of the question which specifically called for hints.

Comment: @Moron, nice. O(n + y log y) in O(n)

Comment: I appreciate all the hints: this is the first homework we are given out, and we have not covered any selection algorithms in this semester yet; I had no clue what the hints meant as a result, but reading up on selection algorithms helped.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sqrt(x) grows faster than log(x), so O(x*sqrt(x)) is worse than O(n*log(x)).  So you have not (yet) done better than sorting the whole list.

There are several ways to solve this problem.  For one of them look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms and look at all of the common sorting algorithms.  Which algorithm can give you the first few elements most efficiently?

Comment: There are *heaps* of good sorting algorithms on that page... :)

Answer (score 0):

> where 1<=y<=sqrt(x)

Note what this requirement gives you.  If y ≤ √x, then y log y ≤ (√x log x) / 2 ∈ O(x<sup>½</sup> log x) ⊂ O(x).

Sort-then-filter may be out the window, but filter-then-sort is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

For y, use the quick sort ideas, picking a random number and partition it into 2 parts.
Part1(smaller) and part2(bigger).

If length of Part1 < y, then do the partition in Part2 with y' = y - len(Part1)
If length of Part1 > y, then do the partition in Part1 with y' = y
If length of Part1 == y, then sort Part1.

For partitioning, average should be almost in O(n) ( I can't approve it now, but it is very quick)( I will try to find some material for this part )..

Sort for y requires ylog(y) < sqrt(x) log ( sqrt(x) ) -> 1/2 * sqrt(x) * log(x) < 1/2 * sqrt(x) * sqrt(x) => 1/2 x.

Comment: That's a very detailed and specific hint.  And the running time is on average O(n).  But your worst case performance is O(n*n), not O(n).  I don't know whether that is sufficient for this homework problem.

Answer (score -1):

You only want a hint, right?

Read the comment by random_hacker *very* carefully in case you missed the big hint that he is giving. There is one algorithm for sorting an array where a tiny, tiny change will produce your algorithm.

In general, if y is not restricted to sqrt (x), you get an algorithm that works in O (x + y * log x), which is O (x) if y = O (x / log x), which is of course the case when y <= sqrt (x).

Comment: hint @gnasher: have a peek at the dates, thezhaba may well be a lecturer by now.